# How do I make a working team changer GUI in roblox?

Tags: roblox

In 2018 Roblox switched coding platforms I believe, most scripts have survived, however I have failed to find a working team changer for myself this year that changes your team when clicked depending if you are in certian groups or not. My scripter says that it works in studio, but an error pops up in game that says "
TeamColor is not a valid member of PlayerGui
Stack Begin
Script 'Players.Benyal.PlayerGui.Starter GUI.TeamGui.Frame.Research and Development.LocalScript', Line 8 
Stack End"
My scipter tried many different ways but it just wont work! Any seggustions?

Comment: Could you please post the code from the local script at "Players.Benyal.PlayerGui.Starter GUI.TeamGui.Frame.Research and Development.LocalScript" as that would let me see what's going wrong a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

**This solution uses two scripts (one LocalScript and one Script), follow the steps below to make a team changing GUI!**

```
local teams = game:GetService("Teams")
local settings = {
    ["GUIHeight"] = 30, --put in a number over 20, or 100 if you want it to fill the screen
    ["GUIWidth"] = 40, --put in a number over 20, or 100 if you want it to fill the screen
    ["GUIColor"] = Color3.fromRGB(240,240,240), --color of the team changer gui

    ["TitleText"] = "Team Changer", --title text in the gui
    ["TitleFont"] = "ArialBold", --font of title
}

repeat wait() until game.Players.LocalPlayer and game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local teamGUI = Instance.new("ScreenGui",plr.PlayerGui)
local frame = Instance.new("Frame",teamGUI)
frame.AnchorPoint,frame.Size,frame.Position,frame.BackgroundColor3 = Vector2.new(0.5,0.5),UDim2.new(settings.GUIWidth/100,0,settings.GUIHeight/100,0),UDim2.new(0.5,0,0.5,0),settings.GUIColor

local title = Instance.new("TextLabel",frame)
title.Text,title.Font,title.Size,title.TextScaled,title.BackgroundTransparency = settings.TitleText,settings.TitleFont,UDim2.new(1,0,0.15,0),true,0.5

local closebutton = Instance.new("TextButton",title)
closebutton.Size,closebutton.Position,closebutton.BackgroundColor3,closebutton.Text = UDim2.new(0.1,0,1,0),UDim2.new(0.9,0,0,0),Color3.fromRGB(255,155,155),"Close"

local list = Instance.new("ScrollingFrame",frame)
list.Size,list.Position,list.BackgroundTransparency = UDim2.new(1,0,0.85,0),UDim2.new(0,0,0.15,0),1

local UILayout = Instance.new("UIListLayout",list)

local serverTeamHandler = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("teamChanger")
local getTeams = teams:GetChildren() --this part checks if you have teams in your game (you need to have put the teams in your game already)
for i,v in pairs(getTeams) do
    print("[Team " .. i .. " found]: " .. v:GetFullName())
    local teamButton = Instance.new("TextButton",list)
    teamButton.BackgroundColor3 = v.TeamColor.Color
    teamButton.Size = UDim2.new(1,0,0,40)

    teamButton.Text,teamButton.TextColor3,teamButton.TextStrokeTransparency,teamButton.TextScaled = v.Name,Color3.fromRGB(255,255,255),0.7,true
    teamButton.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
        print("You changed teams. You are now in: " .. v.Name)
        serverTeamHandler:InvokeServer(v)
    end)
end

closebutton.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.5,0,2,0),"Out","Quad",0.5)
    local returnButton = Instance.new("TextButton",teamGUI)
    returnButton.Size,returnButton.Position,returnButton.Text,returnButton.TextScaled = UDim2.new(0,200,0,50),UDim2.new(0.5,-100,1,-50),"Open Team Changer",true
    returnButton.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
        returnButton:Destroy()
        frame:TweenPosition(UDim2.new(0.5,0,0.5,0),"Out","Elastic",1,true)
    end)
end)
```

**Step 1** Insert a LocalScript into StarterGui

**Step 2** Copy the stuff above and paste it into this LocalScript

**Step 3** Insert a Script into either Workspace or ServerScriptService (your choice)

**Step 4** Copy the stuff below and paste it into the Script

```
local teamChanger = Instance.new("RemoteFunction",game.ReplicatedStorage)
teamChanger.Name = "teamChanger"

local function changeTeam(client,team)
    print(client.Name .. "changed teams: now in" .. team.Name)
    client.Team = team
end

teamChanger.OnServerInvoke = changeTeam
```

**If you followed these steps correctly, you should now have a working team changing GUI in your game!** It works as long as you have already inserted Teams in your game. The first few lines in the LocalScript can also be customized as well!